# Alternate pipeline runners for Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-flink

I read that [Cloudera adapted](https://github.com/cloudera/spark-dataflow) the Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline runner to run on Spark and also that [Data Artisans adapted](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-dataflow) it to run on Flink. It's unclear if Cloudera implemented both batch and windowed streaming, one post said no, but other posts seem not to mention it, as though it's included, while Data Artisans clearly indicates that streaming support is being worked on for Flink.

Is there a page from Google or another Dataflow maintainer which lists all the existing alternate pipeline runners? In lieu of this would anyone care to maintain a canonical bulleted list of implementations? It doesn't seem as though [Google Cloud Platform](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/) is eager as yet to pull in non-Google implementations, probably because that makes keeping the external repository in sync with the internal version more direct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Google Cloud Dataflow SDK Runners" section of https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/partners has a list of existing runners.

Regarding streaming support, the Spark runner written by Cloudera currently does not support it.